# Trying to understand Adobe AIR and full screen mode

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, air, flash

[This adobe's page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e31.html) says that:

> In Flash Player, full-screen mode can
>   only be initiated through ActionScript
>   in response to a mouse click
>   (including right-click) or keypress.
>   AIR content running in the application
>   security sandbox does not require that
>   full-screen mode be entered in
>   response to a user gesture.

I thought [Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/) was a development tool. But this text above is making look like it is either a player, as it is comparing it to the Flash Player.

So, is AIR both development tool and a player?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AIR is not a development tool but rather an application runtime that allows Flex/ActionScript apps to run as a desktop application instead of within a browser window.  One advantage of compiling your app as an AIR app is that it is not limited by the security sandbox that comes with running code within a browser.  This means you can read/write files, go into fullscreen mode without constraints, etc.  On the downside it requires the user to install your application (as well as the AIR runtime, if not already installed) rather than simply accessing your app via a webpage.  Hope that helps clarify things for you.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it clarifies too much! But, in [this](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/) page, it really looks like a development tool either, is it really just a player?

Comment: Yes, it really is just a runtime (player). There are some additional AIR-specific classes you can use when creating a Flex-based AIR app too.  Although you don't need to use Flex to develop AIR apps, you can create AIR apps using any of a number of tools: http://www.adobe.com/products/air/tools/

Comment: AIR is not just for "Flex/ActionScript apps". You can also create HTML/JavaScript apps.